# How to save a video transcript to text file?

Tags: python, video-processing

On a computer with Python 3 and Ubuntu 16.04, I'm trying to use the autosub (https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub)

I installed FFmpeg on Ubuntu (command example - http://www.codebind.com/linux-tutorials/install-ffmpeg-ubuntu-16-04/) and then pip install autosub

On the Terminal I went to a directory with this file: video1.wmv

It is a video in Brazilian Portuguese, that I want to obtain a file with the transcriptions of the lines

Please, is this command what I should type?

```
autosub -S pt -D pt video1.wmv
```

And then how to save in a .TXT file?

Detail:
I typed the:

```
autosub -S pt -D pt video1.wmv
```

But this error appeared:

```
File "/home/reinaldo/Documentos/Code/ti/bin/autosub", line 136
print "The given file does not exist: {0}".format(filename)
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You said you are using Python 3. Shouldn't you be using print with parentheses?

Comment: Thank you. Write it this way? autosub -S pt -D pt ('video1.wmv')

Comment: Error also appears

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub.git
```

will install the latest version from github master which already handled this issue.

Comment: This problem and solution still work in 2022

Answer (score 1):

> print "The given file does not exist: {0}".format(filename)
>       ^
>       SyntaxError: `invalid syntax`

**(1)** *"invalid syntax"* because you gave wrong instruction. Try as:

```
print ( "The given file does not exist: {0}".format(filename) )
```

**(2)** Regarding *"Please, is this command what I should type?"*:

Your `autosub -S pt -D pt video1.wmv` has no API key for Google Translate.

The app says it makes *"requests to [**`Google Web Speech API`**](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/) to generate transcriptions (subs)"*

```
usage: autosub [-h] [-C CONCURRENCY] [-o OUTPUT] [-F FORMAT] [-S SRC_LANGUAGE]
               [-D DST_LANGUAGE] [-K API_KEY] [--list-formats]
               [--list-languages]
               [source_path]

positional arguments:
  source_path           Path to the video or audio file to subtitle

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -C CONCURRENCY, --concurrency CONCURRENCY
                        Number of concurrent API requests to make
  -o OUTPUT, --output OUTPUT
                        Output path for subtitles (by default, subtitles are
                        saved in the same directory and name as the source
                        path)
  -F FORMAT, --format FORMAT
                        Destination subtitle format
  -S SRC_LANGUAGE, --src-language SRC_LANGUAGE
                        Language spoken in source file
  -D DST_LANGUAGE, --dst-language DST_LANGUAGE
                        Desired language for the subtitles
  -K API_KEY, --api-key API_KEY
                        The Google Translate API key to be used. (Required for
                        subtitle translation)
  --list-formats        List all available subtitle formats
  --list-languages      List all available source/destination languages
```